# How to validate asp.net textbox inside grid view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, validation

I am trying to validate asp textbox inside grid-view but my challenge is that i have 3 item templates in my aspx page,

```
ID
Question
Answer
```

i want to put some validation on the Answer field where users have to enter specific answer only based on the ID.  If ID = 1 then they can only enter age number like 1 to 99.  If ID = 2 then they can only enter some kind height values like 5.3, 5.8 etc.  Here is how my current grid view look like

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV_Test" runat="server"  
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    ShowFooter="True" DataKeyNames="ID">
                    <Columns>

                        <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="Question ID" Visible="true">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblQST_SK" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>


                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="150px" HeaderText="Questions">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblQuestions" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question")%>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>                                
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Answer">                              
                                <ItemTemplate>                               
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtAn" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("Answer")%>' ></asp:TextBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>

                </asp:GridView>
```

How can i resolve this issue?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add onkeypress to your itemtemplate like below:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAn" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Eval("Answer")%>' onkeypress='<%#"DecideHowToValidateThisID("+ Eval("Id") +");"%>' ></asp:TextBox>
```

write a javascript function `"DecideHowToValidateThisID(id)"` and based on the id you get as input you can decide how to validate that textbox.

This approach works if u have a small set of predefined ID's along with how to validate

---

The best way would be to have an itemdatabound event for your grid - find out what validation is to be done and add that to your row

[Check out this link for an example](http://forums.asp.net/t/1344808.aspx?applying%20javascript%20to%20textbox%20in%20datalist%20)